# Install pandas/numpy on Alpine-based libreoffice image

Tags: pandas, docker, libreoffice, alpine-linux, blas

I need a Docker image that has both LibreOffice installed AND python pandas.  I've decided that there's a bunch of licensing issues with LibreOffice now because the Oracle's JRE/JDK requirements.  So, I'm starting `FROM linuxserver/libreoffice:7.2.2` in my Docker image.  Now, the problem is that when I try to install pandas using a virtual environment and a requirements.txt file (only line in it is `pandas>=1.4.0,<1.5`) like this:

```bash
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# Install dependencies:
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN /opt/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

...I get this massive error:

```
#9 50.08       Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10
#9 50.08         Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.4.18-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
#9 50.08       Collecting numpy==1.19.3
#9 50.08         Downloading numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB)
#9 50.08            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#9 50.08         Installing build dependencies: started
#9 50.08         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#9 50.08         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#9 50.08         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#9 50.08         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#9 50.08         Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
#9 50.08         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 50.08
#9 50.08         × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#9 50.08         │ exit code: 1
#9 50.08         ╰─> [236 lines of output]
#9 50.08             Running from numpy source directory.
#9 50.08             setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
#9 50.08               run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
#9 50.08             Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
#9 50.08             Cythonizing sources
#9 50.08             blas_opt_info:
#9 50.08             blas_mkl_info:
#9 50.08             customize UnixCCompiler
#9 50.08               libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             blis_info:
#9 50.08               libraries blis not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             openblas_info:
#9 50.08               libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
#9 50.08             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 50.08               libraries tatlas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_3_10_blas_info:
#9 50.08               libraries satlas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_blas_threads_info:
#9 50.08             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 50.08               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_blas_info:
#9 50.08               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             accelerate_info:
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 50.08                 Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
#9 50.08                 Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
#9 50.08                 A better performance should be easily gained by switching
#9 50.08                 Blas library.
#9 50.08               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 50.08             blas_info:
#9 50.08               libraries blas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 50.08                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
#9 50.08                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#9 50.08                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
#9 50.08                 the BLAS environment variable.
#9 50.08               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 50.08             blas_src_info:
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
#9 50.08                 Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
#9 50.08                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#9 50.08                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
#9 50.08                 the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
#9 50.08               if self._calc_info(blas):
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
#9 50.08             lapack_opt_info:
#9 50.08             lapack_mkl_info:
#9 50.08               libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             openblas_lapack_info:
#9 50.08               libraries openblas not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             openblas_clapack_info:
#9 50.08               libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             flame_info:
#9 50.08               libraries flame not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_3_10_threads_info:
#9 50.08             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08               libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_3_10_info:
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries satlas,satlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08               libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_threads_info:
#9 50.08             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08               libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             atlas_info:
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /opt/venv/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
#9 50.08               libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08               libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
#9 50.08             <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             lapack_info:
#9 50.08               libraries lapack not found in ['/opt/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
#9 50.08                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
#9 50.08                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
#9 50.08                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
#9 50.08                 the LAPACK environment variable.
#9 50.08               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#9 50.08             lapack_src_info:
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
#9 50.08                 Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
#9 50.08                 Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
#9 50.08                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
#9 50.08                 the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
#9 50.08               return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
#9 50.08               NOT AVAILABLE
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
#9 50.08               FOUND:
#9 50.08                 language = c
#9 50.08                 define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
#9 50.08
#9 50.08             /usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
#9 50.08               warnings.warn(msg)
#9 50.08             running dist_info
#9 50.08             running build_src
#9 50.08             build_src
#9 50.08             building py_modules sources
#9 50.08             creating build
#9 50.08             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9
#9 50.08             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy
#9 50.08             creating build/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/distutils
#9 50.08             building library "npymath" sources
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable gfortran
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable f95
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable ifort
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable ifc
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable lf95
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable pgfortran
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable nvfortran
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable f90
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable f77
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable fort
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable efort
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable efc
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable g77
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable g95
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable pathf95
#9 50.08             Could not locate executable nagfor
#9 50.08             don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
#9 50.08             Traceback (most recent call last):
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/tmpqq2gyha2_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
#9 50.08                 main()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/tmpqq2gyha2_in_process.py", line 345, in main
#9 50.08                 json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/tmpqq2gyha2_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
#9 50.08                 return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6370icr8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
#9 50.08                 self.run_setup()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6370icr8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
#9 50.08                 super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6370icr8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
#9 50.08                 exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
#9 50.08               File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
#9 50.08                 setup_package()
#9 50.08               File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
#9 50.08                 setup(**metadata)
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
#9 50.08                 return old_setup(**new_attr)
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6370icr8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
#9 50.08                 return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
#9 50.08               File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
#9 50.08                 dist.run_commands()
#9 50.08               File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
#9 50.08                 self.run_command(cmd)
#9 50.08               File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#9 50.08                 cmd_obj.run()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6370icr8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
#9 50.08                 egg_info.run()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 24, in run
#9 50.08                 self.run_command("build_src")
#9 50.08               File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
#9 50.08                 self.distribution.run_command(command)
#9 50.08               File "/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
#9 50.08                 cmd_obj.run()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
#9 50.08                 self.build_sources()
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
#9 50.08                 self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
#9 50.08                 sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
#9 50.08               File "/tmp/pip-install-m9ffqtsd/numpy_f52b823899c842e29073892fb891d2ea/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
#9 50.08                 source = func(extension, build_dir)
#9 50.08               File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 663, in get_mathlib_info
#9 50.08                 raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
#9 50.08             RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
#9 50.08             [end of output]
#9 50.08
#9 50.08         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 50.08       error: metadata-generation-failed
#9 50.08
#9 50.08       × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#9 50.08       ╰─> See above for output.
#9 50.08
#9 50.08       note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#9 50.08       hint: See above for details.
#9 50.08       [end of output]
#9 50.08
#9 50.08   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 50.09 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 50.09
#9 50.09 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#9 50.09 │ exit code: 1
#9 50.09 ╰─> See above for output.
#9 50.09
#9 50.09 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /opt/venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip &&     pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

I've looked around at several answers listed [here](https://gist.github.com/orenitamar/f29fb15db3b0d13178c1c4dd611adce2) that seem very similar to what I'm getting, but this discussion seems pretty old and out of date.  None of the solutions I've tried from there are working.

It looks like BLAS and a couple of other items aren't installed correctly on the Alpine image.  I've tried a bunch of different ways to do this and none have worked so far.  How can I install pandas on [this Alpine Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/libreoffice/linuxserver/libreoffice/7.2.2/images/sha256-49c3bee22ea312b79a98c86baf36ce20afb6f8f8f8760febfecfc4699c3c9ef3?context=explore)?

### UPDATE

I'd be willing to use a Debian or Ubuntu-based Docker image as long as it comes preloaded with LibreOffice.  The only image I've found online, so far, that comes with LibreOffice preloaded is an Alpine image...

Comment: Using a Debian or Ubuntu-based image potentially works better here.  My memory is that Libreoffice is not small; are you actually getting a noticeable image-size or other benefit from using Alpine instead?

Comment: I'm open to using a Docker image that is Debian or Ubuntu-based as long as it comes preloaded with LibreOffice.  Do you know of one like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `openjdk`, but I'm not sure.

As for pandas, it's missing BLAS C libraries that can only be installed with apk. You can do that easily by running `apk add openblas`, but you might need also the `openblas-dev` package as well.

Comment: installing `openblas` and `openblas-dev` didn't fix the issue when using the Alpine image.  I tried using a conda image that I believe is Debian (`continuumio/miniconda3:4.10.3`) and was unable to `apt-get install openjdk` --> " Unable to locate package openjdk"

Comment: On Debian you could try the `openjdk-11-jre` package. Depending on what version you need

Comment: I got it working by addding this to the Dockerfile `RUN apk add build-base python3-dev`
However, it is very slow because it compiles numpy and pandas from source.
If you don't really have to use this specific pandas version (>=1.4.0,<1.5) I would rather suggest installing the alpine package `py3-pandas` it is the 1.3.2 version.

Comment: version 1.3.2 of pandas would probably work.  Is the installation just `RUN apk py3-pandas`?

Comment: `RUN apk add py3-pandas` yes. I would advise always to use apk's packages over pip install, except only if you have to use legacy versions of python modules because of compatibility issues, or if it is not available in the alpine repository, but they mostly are.